# Source a script in PHP command-line

Tags: php, command-line

How can I "source" a script in PHP command-line?

For example, I have a script test.php which contains

```
<?php $test = '123456'; ?>
```

I would like to use `$test` in the interactive mode, so when I run `php -a` the variable already would be defined.

Comment: What do you mean interactive mode ? Do you have an example ?

Comment: You can use `require` in interactive mode just like you would in a script. Or do you want to automatically preload this script whenever you start php?

Answer (score 0):

$argv array (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

in your case

```
$test = $argv[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you save a file as test.php, and then run it, like this:

```
php test.php foo test anothertest
```

You'll get the following output from the script:

```
test.php
foo
test
anothertest
```

As you can see, the first argument is actually the name of your PHP script, which is consistent with many other languages that use this "ARGV" functionality.

Note that you can also access the PHP command line args as array elements, like this:

```
echo $argv[0];
echo $argv[1];
```